Converting a QML url (file:///) to a local path string (/ or C:\)
The selectedFile property of a FormDialog looks like a URI when converted to a string:

FolderDialog {
    onAccepted: monitorForm.monitorPath = selectedFolder
}

Label {
    text: monitorForm.monitorPath
}

I need it to be displayed as a local path:

Another question asks for a way to do this using QML. The answers to this question implement their own ways of handling differences between platforms (except the top answer, which only works correctly on Windows and removes the leading slash on Linux). I'm hoping there's a way to leverage PySide to do this automatically.

In Python, you can use QUrl.toLocalFile, and in QML (Qt 6.*), you can use new URL(url).pathname ref.

According to the documentation, you can use the toLocalFile function to convert a URL path to a local file path, or use fromLocalFile for the reverse operation.
print(QUrl("file:/home/user/file.txt").toLocalFile()) # "/home/user/file.txt"

Also in QML, there is no direct method to access the toLocalFile function of a URL object. However, in Qt 6.*, we can convert our URL to a JavaScript URL type and then retrieve the pathname.
const path = new URL(url).pathname;


Note: Using URL is not a typical method for retrieving a file path, so it should be used with caution.

Additionally, since a slash is always added to the beginning of the output path, for a Windows path, you should also append .substr(1) at the end.
const path = new URL(url).pathname.substr(platform.os == "windows" ? 1 : 0);


In C++, QUrl::toString() takes a QUrl::UrlFormattingOption -- one of which is QUrl::PreferLocalFile:

If the URL is a local file according to isLocalFile() and contains no query or fragment, a local file path is returned.

PySide6 provides toString() as well, but due to a bug, toString() wants a QUrl.ComponentFormattingOption instead of a QUrl.UrlFormattingOption. QUrl.ComponentFormattingOption doesn't have a PreferLocalFile flag, but we can turn a QUrl.UrlFormattingOption into a QUrl.ComponentFormattingOption as follows:
QUrl.ComponentFormattingOption.PrettyDecoded | QUrl.UrlFormattingOption.PreferLocalFile

The full code:
GridLayout { // The root element
    id: monitorForm
    signal folderSelected(folder: string)
    property string monitorPath

    Label {
        text: monitorForm.monitorPath
    }
    FolderDialog {
        onAccepted: monitorForm.folderSelected(selectedFolder)
    }
}

import sys
from PySide6.QtCore import QUrl
from PySide6.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide6.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine

app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
engine.load('main.qml')

root = engine.rootObjects()[0]

def assign_url_to_monitorPath(x):
    root.setProperty('monitorPath', x.toString(QUrl.ComponentFormattingOption.PrettyDecoded | QUrl.UrlFormattingOption.PreferLocalFile))

root.folderSelected.connect(assign_url_to_monitorPath)

exit(app.exec())

